# Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63830" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

From my application I am opening a window in pop up and later on I am periodically watching the current url of that newly open window by below code but it is giving the below error Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:63830" from accessing a cross-origin frame. How to solve this issue

```
 var _url =
        "https://us.lightspeedapp.com/oauth/authorize.php?response_type=code&client_id=8f2a3974b288e34327ad5564b2f7c0c5f7e28103893479b1e53a957b5de2e0ff&scope=employee:all";

    var loggedIn = false;
    var win = window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600');


    var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {
        try {
            debugger;
            console.log(win.document.URL);
            if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                var url = win.document.URL;
                win.close();


            }
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }, 500);

    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error message because the server that served the HTML file is located under a different domain then the AJAX url you are trying to call.

There are multiple ways of dealing with this.

Read more about CORS [here at mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

I don't know which programing language you are using on that server **us.lightspeedapp.com** but as you wrote, you are developing locally on your computer having a webserver running that serves your HTML file.

You need to add **HTTP headers** to the response of **us.lightspeedapp.com**.

The visitors browser doing the Cross-Origin AJAX call does an **OPTION** HTTP call before doing the actual POST, GET or whatever call.

This **OPTION** call tells the browser if the server is OK with the request of that origin.

A request -> response could look like that (depending on your need).

**Request Header** (Visitor Browser)

```
OPTIONS /oauth/authorize.php
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, x-requested-with
Origin: http://localhost:63830
```

**Response Header** (Webserver)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-myapikey, x-userid
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

**IMPORTANT!** 
The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header needs the protocol (http,https) matching too! You can also have a whitelist of origins on that server, and compare the request **Origin** Header with that whitelist, and add the entry to the response header if found, or answer with 401 Not allowed.

**Have fun developing!**